# how to select all check box in filtered data table in php?

Tags: javascript, php

How to select all checkbox in filtered data only in php table?? I use option selection as filter.
I have try with javascript but it select all also the unfiltered data.

this is my code

```
<?php
//cek session
if(empty($_SESSION['admin'])){
    $_SESSION['err'] = '<center>Anda harus login terlebih dahulu!</center>';
    header("Location: ./");
    die();
} else {
include_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
$akun=$_SESSION['nama_akun'];
$userid=$_SESSION['user_id'];
$i = 1;
$kontak = $db->daftarKontak($userid); ?>
        <!-- Row Start -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Secondary Nav START -->
            <div class="col s12">
                <nav class="secondary-nav">
                    <div class="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-1">
                        <ul class="left">
                            <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a class="judul"><i class="material-icons">mail</i> Daftar Kontak</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- Secondary Nav END -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <div class="col m12" id="colres">
                    <form id="kontak" class="col s12" method="POST" action="?page=tuj" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <br>
                        <select id="myInput" onChange="myFunction(event)" placeholder="Cari Grup" title="Type in a name">
                            <Option value="">Semua Kontak</option>
                            <option value="KADIV">KADIV</option>
                            <option value="KABAG">KABAG</option>
                            <option value="KASIE">KASIE</option>
                            <option value="BAG.">Bagian Bagian</option>
                            <option value="CABANG">Pimpinan Cabang</option>
                            <option value="AST">Asisten</option>
                            <option value="CAPEM">Pimpinan Capem</option>
                            <option value="KASPEM">Pimpinan Kaspem</option>
                            <option value="STAF">STAF</option>
                            <option value="CSO">CSO</option>
                            <option value="PINJ">Pinjaman</option>
                            <option value="ICU">ICU</option>
                        </select>
                        <b><label for="myInput">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Tampilkan Kontak Per Grup:</label></b>

                        <input type="text" id="Pilih" onSelect="nilai()" onkeypress="return cegah(event)" onkeyup="Function()" placeholder="Cari Berdasarkan Nama" title="Type in a name">

                         <?php  echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 261); ?><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this, 'tujuan[]')" align="center" id="select_all"><label for="select_all"> PILIH SEMUA</label>


                        <center><table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" width="100%">
                            <style>
                                th, td {
                                    text-align: left;
                                    padding: 8px;
                                }

                                tr:nth-child(even){background-color: white}

                                th {
                                    background-color: grey ;
                                    color: white;
                                }
                            </style>
                            <br><thead>                     
                              <tr>
                                <th width="15%">No.</th>
                                <th width="30%">Nama</th>
                                <th width="40%">Nama Akun</th>
                                <th width="15%">Pilih</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead></br>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                    foreach($kontak as $value){
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $value['NAMA'];?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $value['NAMA_AKUN'];?></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="tujuan[]" id="<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $value['USER_ID'];?>"><label for="<?php echo $i ?>"></label></td>


                                    <?php
                                        $i++;
                                    ?>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                            </table></center>
                            <script>
                            function myFunction() {
                              var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
                              input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                              filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                              table = document.getElementById("data-table");
                              tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                              for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
                                if (td) {
                                  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                                  } else {
                                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                                  }
                                }       
                              }
                            }
                            </script>

                            <script language="JavaScript">
                              function toggle(source, id) {
                                      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(id);
                                      for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                                          checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
                                      }
                              }
                            </script>

                                <script>
                                   function pilsemh(master,group){
                                  var cbArray = document.getElementsByClassName(group);
                                  for(var i=0; i < cbArray.length; i++){
                                   var cb = document.getElementById(cbArray[i].id);
                                   cb.checked = master.checked;

                                  }
                                   }
                                  </script>


                            <script>
                            function Function(e) {
                              var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
                              input = document.getElementById("Pilih");
                              filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                              table = document.getElementById("data-table");
                              tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                              for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                                if (td) {
                                  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                                  } else {
                                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                                  }
                                }       
                              }
                              e = e || window.event;
                              var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
                              return key !== 13; 
                            }

                            </script>
                            <script>
                                function cegah(e) {
                                    document.getElementById("myInput").value="";
                                    e = e || window.event;
                                    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
                                    return key !== 13; 
                                }
                            </script>

                            <button type="submit" name="kirim" class="btn-large blue waves-effect waves-light">Lanjut <i class="material-icons">done</i></button>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Row in form END -->

        </div>
            <!-- Form END -->
```

I think  the code might contain several errors and I'am trying to find them. I would appreciate any suggestions.
thank you